# HTMLunit suppress errors: deprecated?

Tags: java, error-handling, htmlunit

I am trying to suppress the JavaScript errors that HTMLunit almost always shows when loading a page.

But strangely enough, the following code does not work:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

public class HttpClientLogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        HttpClientLogin logInNow = new HttpClientLogin();

        logInNow.loadPage();
    }

    public void loadPage() throws Exception {

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        HtmlPage currentPage = webClient.getPage("the url link here");

            webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

        String textSource = currentPage.asText();
        String xmlSource = currentPage.asXml();

        System.out.println(xmlSource);
    }
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
The method setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(boolean) is undefined for the type WebClient
```

Are these methods deprecated or am I using the wrong package?

Comment: Have you tried specifying what browser toolkit is your WebClient using? Ex: `new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);`

Comment: @EvertonAgner: Yes I tried: didn't work :(

Comment: Well, since the error is setThrowException**OnFailingStatusCode** I would assume an HTTP Error is happening. Does the page opens with no error if you get this URL and opens in your web browser?

Comment: Also, are you getting the HTMLUnit dependency from Maven or putting it manually? Which version?

Comment: I have `htmlunit-2.13.jar`

Comment: Do you mind showing me the URL? Is it public?

Comment: I'm trying to simulate a login on the url `https://investorshub.advfn.com/boards/login.aspx`

Comment: I see what happened, is pretty much simplier than what I thought. Check my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(boolean)` is defined in the `WebClientOptions` class, not in `WebClient`.

```
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
```

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html#setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

The setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(boolean) is defined on the both the class webClient and WebClientOptions.